# Annotation RequestMapping() giving the error

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am starting with Spring Boot and trying to make a Rest service.
I am writing a controller where there are RequestMappings to 3 methods.
Two of them are working fine while the thirl annotation is giving this error while writing the code.

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete     EnumHeader
>     - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete    EnumDeclaration

I tried everything from other answers but cant seem to find out the issue. Here is my code for the Controller-

```
package io.springboot.topics;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TopicsController {

    @Autowired
    private TopicSrvice topicService;

    @RequestMapping("/topics")
    public List<Topic> getAllTopics() {
        return topicService.getAllTopics();
    }
    @RequestMapping("/topics/{id}")
    public Topic getTopic(@PathVariable String id) {
        return topicService.getTopic(id);
    }

 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/topics")
```

}

The error is coming in the last line ie last Requestmapping().

Comment: where is the method for the last `RequestMapping`?

Comment: Have you tried annotating method with GetMapping and PostMapping instead of RequestMapping?

Comment: Yeah. I tried it. That is also not working. I dont understand, if it is working for the above two cases, why is it giving this editor error for the third one? Am i missing some syntax or something?

Comment: Please add the method to your question. You obviously  forgot to add it.

Comment: Are you getting any runtime or compile time error as well?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for those that are just finding this issue: You need to type in the actual method under the @RequestMapping. Eclipse gives an issue when you stop at this stage but once you write your method, you are good to go. At least that is what worked for me.

So:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/topics")
public ... {
//your method
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are writing /topics URL for two methods,one for GET and one for POST,Spring does not support this configuration,You can either change url for two different methods or you can write a single method having url /topics with array of HttpMethod like method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }